# How to get inline-blocks to make space for floats?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-float

I have an inline-block element containing a floating element, and some text that is to flow around it:

```
<div style="background: yellow; display: inline-block">
  <div style="float: left; width: 128px; height: 128px; background: cyan">Float</div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br><br>
  Vivamus blandit porta rhoncus.<br><br>
  Integer egestas, lectus ac finibus sagittis, nisl diam scelerisque risus, id malesuada odio tortor in elit.<br><br>
  Sed pellentesque ligula enim, at porta nibh viverra quis.<br><br>
  Integer egestas, lectus ac finibus sagittis, nisl diam scelerisque risus, id malesuada odio tortor in elit.
</div>
```

On Internet Explorer, this renders as expected:
[image]
Firefox and Chrome render the same HTML differently: 
[image]

Notice how in the Firefox rendering, the width of the inline-block is such that it precisely fits the text *without the float*. This causes lines that do not fit once the float is added in to break unnecessarily.

It would appear that Firefox and Chrome render this construction by first (1) computing the preferred width of the inline-block as if the float weren't there, (2) adding the float, and (3) laying out the flowing text around the float while using the width computed in (1) as the width of the inline-block.

The behavior I *want* here is the behavior implemented by Internet Explorer. Is there any way to achieve the same effect in other browsers such as Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things should work. First question, are you using a doctype and which one?

Comment: @Rob: I am not using IE as a reference for how things *should* work, I'm using it as an example for how I *want* things to work. I am pretty sure the CSS specification leaves this detail unspecified, allowing for both behaviors. This is IE11 using a html5 doctype.

Comment: No. CSS does not do that. My comment was only to be sure you are aware that no version of IE can be trusted to do much of anything correctly.

Comment: @Rob: In section 10.3.5 of the CSS 2.2 specification describing the shrink-to-fit width, "CSS 2.2 does not define the exact algorithm."

Comment: Are the font sizes the same? They don't look the same in the images. Check dev tools

Comment: They are unspecified; the snippet above is the whole code up to boilerplate. But the exact fit of the inline-block to the third line versus the fifth line makes it quite clear that nothing of that sort is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a specific font-size to the text or else it will take default size as set in the browser which may be different. Also give some width to the wrapper element so that the text flow get same amount of space for all the cases.

Comment: I don't want the inline-block to have the same amount of space in both browsers. I want them to have the amount of space necessary to accommodate the text, without linebreaking if possible.